# What is ament_python?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to create some documentation for `ament_python`. But I don't even know where to start. It does not seem to be a package. There is no entry in https://index.ros.org/search/?term=ament_python&section=pkgs. There is this abandoned repo: https://github.com/ament/ament_python But it must be defined somewhere, because it can be defined as build_type, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412339/what-is-ament_python?/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2023-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-02-09**:
I found some entries for `ament_python` in the ROS2 GitHub: https://github.com/ament/ament_package, https://github.com/ament/ament_package/blob/rolling/package.xml, did you check it?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2023-02-10**:
Yes, I found those too. But I think this is not relevant since ament is not used as build tool anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I found it: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-ros/blob/master/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2023-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1